# copying files into named directories in bash

Tags: bash

I have a directory structure like so
/dir01/dir02/files

I want to copy the first file in dir02 onto a separate drive and into a directory with the same name as dir01

I wrote the following script

```
while [ "${*}" != "" ] ; do

INPUT="${1}"
FOLDER="${INPUT}"/*DPX
TARGET_FOLDER="/Users/user/Desktop/folder"/$(basename "${INPUT}")

for file in "${FOLDER}"; do
    echo cp "$file" "${TARGET_FOLDER}"
    break 1
done
done
```

Here INPUT is dir01 , FOLDER is dir02 and TARGET_FOLDER is the new directory with the same name as dir02 I want the file to copy to.

When I run the script it looks for a folder named *DPX in the INPUT path, which doesn't exist. There are many folders in the INPUT directory named *DPX and I want it to pull the first file from all of them.

Comment: Check current directory or pass dir01 as an absolute path. Insert a `ls $PWD/$INPUT` somewhere to check if you're in the directory you think you are. Also, some `shift` must be missing here or you'll have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks! @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your `for` with:

```
for file in "$INPUT"/*DPX/*
```

Notes:

- Your version is looking for a file called `*DPX` because `${FOLDER}` is quoted on the `for` line.
- `for f in "$dir"` will execute the `for` loop once, with `f=$dir`. To look for files under `$dir`, you need another `/*`.
- Also, you want a `shift` before the last `done`.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Could you perhaps accept the answer?